# Connecting apache and Widfly using mod_cluster

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-9, mod-cluster

I am trying to setup mod_cluster as a reverse proxy for Wildfly 9. When I use http as a protocol (between mod_cluster and Wildfly), everything works just fine (forwarding requests to application server and detecting server).

My problems come up when I try to wire mod_cluster and wildfly using ajp as a protocol. I checked mod_cluster-manager and it seemed that 
mod_cluster was connected to wildfly, but it couldn't forward
requests to application server.

I have the following configuration:

- http server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
- application server: Wildfly 9.0.2
- mod_cluster: 1.3

mod_cluster.conf

```
PersistSlots on
CreateBalancers 1
MemManagerFile /opt/mod_cluster/logs


EnableOptions
AllowDisplay On
AllowCmd On
WaitForRemove 1



UseAlias 1
ServerAdvertise Off

Listen *:5555
<VirtualHost *:5555>
    <Directory />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from 192.168.0.71
        Allow from 192.168.0.71
        Allow from 127
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
     <Location /mcm>
         SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
         Allow from 192.168
         Allow from all
     </Location>
     KeepAliveTimeout 300
     MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
     ManagerBalancerName mycluster
     #AdvertiseFrequency 5
     EnableMCPMReceive

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName my-app.org
    ServerAlias my-app.org
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/user.error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/my_app.access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

    Redirect "/" https://my-app.org
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    #ProxyPass /_error !
    #ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=on
    #ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster


    <Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName my-app.org
    ServerAlias my-app.org
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/user.ssl.error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/my_app.ssl.access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /_error !
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=on
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster
    <Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Wildfly Configuration (relevant fragments):

mod_cluster subsystem:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:2.0">
        <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster"
                            proxies="mc-prox1"
                            advertise="false"
                            sticky-session-force="true" load-balancing-group="mycluster" connector="ajp">
            <dynamic-load-provider>
                <load-metric type="cpu"/>
            </dynamic-load-provider>
        </mod-cluster-config>
    </subsystem>
```

outbound-socket-binding:

```
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mc-prox1">
        <remote-destination host="192.168.0.71" port="5555"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
```

[EDIT]

I should have included ajp configuration:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:1500}">
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:0}" />
 .......
</socket-binding-group>
```

[EDIT2]

When I set ajp port to 8009, it works. I want to use custom port number. 
Does anyone have a clue how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had the wrong binaries :/. After replacing them with the ones from the offical website, I managed to connect Wildfly with apache through AJP.